# Install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 when the normal methods fail

Tags: apt, 20.04, wine

I need to install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04. All the online guides say to just run `sudo apt-get install wine`. So I did this, and then ran `wine --version` to confirm that it was installed correctly. However, it didn't output the version number as I expected. Instead, it said

```
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
```

So, I ran `sudo apt-get install wine32`. But this fails, outputting

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then spent an hour googling, and trying various solutions that worked for other people. I tried purging some packages, I tried getting a different version of Wine from a different repo, I ran `apt-get -f` at one point, I tried some other stuff that I honestly didn't understand; nothing worked for me.

So at this point, I'm starting over. Running `apt list --installed | sed -E 's|(.*)/.*|\1|' | grep -i wine` returns no results, so I think I've successfully removed everything. So, now what should I try to do next?

Comment: Review your /var/log/apt/term.log. Look at the section when you originally installed Wine. Were there any errors or warnings?

Comment: I don't see any errors. https://pastebin.com/W12Q0C0P Although, I think I might've canceled (`ctrl` + `c`) the first wine install part way through. Idk if that messed something up.

Comment: Asking just in case: have you added the i386 architecture? -- it's needed for wine afaik...

Comment: Nah, it's a good question. I have run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. This has not changed the error I get when installing wine32.

Comment: @MathewAlden No solutions yet, but we can keep investigating :) -- are you doing everything as explained in https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu ? ...also wondering why are you expecting version 5 when the current stable release is 7? Maybe there is some package version mix-up or something...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I haven't found an answer yet, but I have found a work-around that might be useful to others.

I can't get Wine to install. But Steam (by Valve) installs just fine. And Steam has a built-in, modified version of Wine called Proton. And Steam allows you to launch arbitrary 3rd party apps through its launcher.

So, in your Steam library on the bottom right, click "Add a game" -> "Add a non-Steam game...". Navigate to whichever Windows executable you want to run, and select it. Your program now displays in your Steam library as if it were a game. Now, right-click the program in your steam library, and click "Properties...". On the "Compatibility" tab, select a version of Proton to run your executable in (probably the most recent version). (You may have to check a checkbox before choosing a Proton version.) Close the popup. Now back in your Steam library, select the Windows executable you've set up, and click "Play". Steam will attempt to launch your Windows executable in a Proton runtime environment, including the Steam Overlay, as if it were a game.

This is definitely the wrong way to do this, and I'd appreciate if anyone could help me install Wine normally, but so far this is the only solution I've found.